# A square with different centers and sides of different lengths

Tags: graphics, geometry

As you can see the bottom square is in the ${((0,2),(0,2))}$ range

[image]

- The center of the square is indeterminate
- The length of a square is indeterminate
- The length of the square is indeterminate, and $1/2<\mathrm{edge length}<1$
- have different color

`Rectangle` functions draw squares in Wolfram,But this function doesn't specify the center

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
colorlist = {Red, Blue, Green, Purple};
center := RandomReal[{0, 2}];
length := RandomReal[{1/2, 1}];
pltRect[color_] := Graphics[
   {color, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, length}]},
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}
   ];
Show[pltRect /@ colorlist]
```

[image]

I have a lot of problems with the graph here, I don't know how to define the center, and I draw rectangles instead of squares, right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1.** To get a square of a given center and sidelength, use

```
square[center_,length_]:=With[{aux=length*{1/2,1/2}},
                           Rectangle[center-aux,center+aux]];
```

Then, for example,

```
Show[Graphics[{Purple,square[{1,1},1.5]}],
     Graphics[{Green,square[{2,2},1]}]]
```

gives

[image]

**Part 2.** To get one random square of the kind OP describes, use

```
randomSquare := With[{
    length = RandomReal[{1/2, 1}]},
   With[{center = RandomReal[{length/2, 2 - length/2}, 2]},
    square[center, length]]];
```

To get three, use

```
randomdraw := Show[
  Graphics[{Purple,randomSquare},Axes->True,PlotRange->{{0,2},{0,2}}],
  Graphics[{Green,randomSquare}],
  Graphics[{Red,randomSquare}]]
```

For example, using `SeedRandom[2];randomdraw` I get

[image]

Comment: Equivalent to their own midpoint, feeling pretty hard to think of

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
pltRect[color_, {x_, y_}, length_] := 
  Module[{minX = x - length/2, maxX = x + length/2, 
    minY = y - length/2, maxY = y + length/2},
   Graphics[{color, Rectangle[{minX, minY}, {maxX, maxY}]}, 
    Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]
   ];
p1 = pltRect[Blue, {.5, .5}, 1];
p2 = pltRect[Red, {.5, 1.5}, .7];
p3 = pltRect[Orange, {1.5, 1}, .6];
Show[p1, p2, p3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

I like using `MinMax[]` with its handy second padding argument with `Rectangle[]` for this. Using the same syntax as in user293787's answer:

```
square[center_, length_] :=
      Rectangle @@ Transpose[MinMax[#, length/2] & /@ Transpose[{center}]]
```

Another possibility is to use `RegularPolygon[]`:

```
square[center_, length_] := RegularPolygon[center, length/Sqrt[2], 4]
```

Comment: it is a good ideal

Answer (score 1):

for @user293787 help

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
colorlist = {Red, Blue, Green, Purple};
square[center_, length_] := 
  With[{aux = length*{-1/2, 1/2}}, 
   Rectangle[center - aux, center + aux]];
randomSquare := 
  With[{length = RandomReal[{1/2, 1}]}, 
   With[{center = RandomReal[{length/2, 2 - length/2}, 2]}, 
    square[center, length]]];
Map[Graphics[{#1, Opacity[0.8], randomSquare},
    Axes -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}] &,
  colorlist] // Show
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Is this now what you wanted, or is there still something missing?

Comment: @user293787 yes,It is I want,thank you